# Remove sensitive-data from exception logs during serialize/deserialize JSON content while using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Tags: java, objectmapper, jsonparser, fasterxml, sensitive-data

**Context:**
We are using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper's *readValue()* method to convert JSON to Java POJO. When the *JsonParseException* or *JsonMappingException* occurs, the original data excerpts (JSON content) is being printed in the logs.

**Issue:**
Our JSON may contain sensitive-data, so it shouldn't get logged to meet the security compliance.

The options we are considering...

Option-1:   wrap the readValue() method with *JsonParseException*, *JsonMappingException* and add *clearLocation()*

fyi... *clearLocation()* on *JsonParseException* and *JsonMappingException* removes context information from exception's message

```
        try {
            objectMapper.readValue(jsonContent, pojoObject);
        } catch (JsonParseException | JsonMappingException e) {
            e.clearLocation();
            throw e;
        }
```

The downside of this solution is, *readValue()* method is used in lot of places across multiple applications. So we need to deal with lot of code changes. And we shouldn't forget to call *clearLocation()* in the future implementations.

Option-2:   Create custom ObjectMapper

```
public class CustomObjectMapper {
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    // showing only one method to simplify
    public static <T> T convertJsonToPojo(String content, Class<T> valueType)
            throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(content, valueType);
        } catch (JsonParseException | JsonMappingException e) {
            e.clearLocation();
            throw e;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.clearLocation();
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

**Please let me know if you came across the similar situation and handled it differently.**

Comment: shouldn't log only the fields that you want to see? otherwise even with tools like elk or splunk, searching through the logs are going to be very hectic

Comment: The second option is OK but I would consider using aspects or exception handlers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use aspects;

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class OMAspect {

    @Around("within(<your base package>..*)")
    public Object aroundOMMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        try {
           return joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.clearLocation();
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also thought that using aspects would be a great solution here!